# wxmac image not found (Python 2.7.5, OS X)

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, wxwidgets

I had "brew installed" **wxmac** back in 2012. Recently, I "brew upgraded" and then "cleaned up". Since then, I can no longer import wx:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa/wx/_core_.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9.4.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa/wx/_core_.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Looks like I now have a version newer than 2.9.4:

```
brew install wxmac
Warning: wxmac-3.0.1 already installed
```

Looking at my Python installation, these are the relevant files:

```
ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
wx
wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa
wx.pth
wxPython_common-2.9.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
wxversion.py
wxversion.pyc
```

I'm suspecting that "brew cleanup" removed my older, but working, version of wxmac. Now, either the wxmac version or some symlink is causing the current problem. How should I go about fixing or figuring it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like wxpython files were copied from or symlinked to or just referenced from /Library; Homebrew will never install files to /Library and doesn't know how to manage them if you or an installer placed them there. To use Homebrew wxpython, please remove everything wx-related from your /Library site-packages folder and `brew install wxpython` in addition to `wxmac`.

To use wxpython with system Python, you need to tell Python that your Homebrew site-packages folder is a special "site-packages" folder; having it in sys.path is not enough, because wxpython relies on .pth files that are only processed in special folders. To do this, you can run:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
echo "import site; site.addsitedir('$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages')" >> ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Then, `import wx` should work.

Comment: Hey, Tim. I brew installed wxmac and wxpython. I got stuck in the third step. The "echo" you suggested resulted in `-bash: /Users/smaniato/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth: No such file or directory`

Changing the path to `~/../../Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth` says "permission denied" even when I sudo run it.
As expected, `import wx` now results in `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wx`
Thanks a lot for helping out!

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry: you need to create the path first with `mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`. Edited answer to reflect.